# Sails JS: enhance model before sending response

Tags: model, customization, sails.js

is there any way to put some data into the model before sending it to the client?

For example, the user sends a request to get a list of products and I want to add a property 'comment_count' to each product. How should I do this instead of writing a loop inside the controller?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure my solution is correct. But let take a try on overriding one of the two following methods: `toJSON` & `toObject`. Although the [document](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/records/toObject.html) is poor, you should take a try on this. If the solution does not work. May be you must use a loop statement. Take a look on Underscore or Lodash for convenient :).

---

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `toJSON` instance method to add / remove properties to a model instance, but you can only put *synchronous* code in the method.  A common use case is to remove passwords from a `User` model before returning it:

```
toJSON: function() {

  // Get the plain-object version of this instance
  var obj = this.toObject();

  // Remove the password
  delete obj.password;

  // Return
  return obj;

}
```

`toJSON` is automatically called by Sails' default `res.json` response method.

Unfortunately, "counting comments" is not typically the kind of thing you can do synchronously, since it will require database interaction.  So, `toJSON` is out.  Instead, you can write a `findProducts` class method for the `Product` class which does the normal `Product.find`, and then loops over the results and adds the `comment_count` property to each.  Placing the code in a model class method is better than doing it directly in a controller action, because the class method can be called from anywhere (i.e., it can be used in multiple controllers).